# Get the max value on a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples:

```
card_list= [(2, (1, S)), (0, (12, H)), (1, (5, C)]
```

This list contains cards: (cardindex, (value, suit)) where cardindex is a index to store the position of the card but irrelevant for this my particular question.

So in the example there are 3 cards in the list:

- (2, (1, S)) = Ace of Spades with an index of 2.
- (0, (12, H)) = King
  of Hearts with an index of 0
- (1, (5, C)) = 5 of Clubs with index 1

Well, my question is: I desire to obtain the item with the max value, this is, i have to get the item: (0, (12, H))

My attempt is:

```
CardWithHighestValue= max(card_list,key=itemgetter(1)[0])
```

But I get the item or the value? And the most important: is it really correct that sentence?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So do you just want the card with the highest vale? If there were 2 with the same value, would you tiebreak on suit? I don't think you've quite understood `itemgetter`. It returns a function so the 0th index doesn't make any sense.

Comment: meh.... smells like homework. Go search on SO for similar list operation events. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: @Paul Rooney  I 'd handle the suits in another part (previous) of the code, maybe separating suit lists and then comparing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace

```
CardWithHighestValue= max(card_list,key=itemgetter(1)[0])
```

with

```
CardWithHighestValue= max(card_list,key=itemgetter(1))
```

**Demo**

```
from operator import itemgetter
card_list= [(2, (1, "S")), (0, (12, "H")), (1, (5, "C"))]
print max(card_list,key=itemgetter(1)) 

card_list= [(2, (1, "S")), (0, (4, "H")), (1, (5, "C"))]
print max(card_list,key=itemgetter(1))
```

**Output:**

```
(0, (12, 'H'))
(1, (5, 'C'))
```

Comment: It was simple at last! I thought I had to indicate the index of the sub-tuple in order to search there for the max value, but no!

Comment: You are welcome :). Please accept ans if it solved your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an anonymous function as key:

Demo:

```
print(max(card_list, key=lambda x:x[1]))
```

Output:

```
(0, (12, 'H'))
```

Comment: I guess this is slower according some other posts here in stackoverflow in similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
lst=[(1,('a',10)), (2,('b',10)),(10,('a',10)), (3,('a',10))]
```

So

```
print("min: ", min(lst)[0]) # min: 1
```

And

```
print("max: ", max(lst)[0]) # max:  10
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).