# How to sort array by highest number

Tags: python, list

```
arraydata = [
     ["bob", 56],
     ["Jan", 12],
     ["Foo", -83]
]
```

I want o get the name and number by the highest number display.

```
output:
bob
56
```

I tried to print(max(arraydata))

But that did not work. Any suggestions?
i'm using python

Comment: Duplicate of [Get the max value on a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49362401/get-the-max-value-on-a-list-of-tuples)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the max value on a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49362401/get-the-max-value-on-a-list-of-tuples)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Optimal method to find the max of sublist items within list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38655727/optimal-method-to-find-the-max-of-sublist-items-within-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use a `key` in pythons' `max`:

```
max(arraydata, key=lambda x: x[1])
#['bob', 56]
```

---

Note that by feeding `max` the whole nested list, the first ordering criteria will be the first elements in the sublists, and hence ordering will be lexicographical.

Which is why `bob` comes first (also coincidentally):

```
max(arraydata)
# ['bob', 56]
```

This is explained with:

```
[ord(i[0]) for i in ["bob", "Jan", "Foo"]]
# [98, 74, 70]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the highest you can do:

```
max(arraydata, key=lambda x: x[1])
#['bob', 56]
```

If you need several of the top, you can sort as well:

```
sorted(arraydata, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
#[['bob', 56], ['Jan', 12], ['Foo', -83]]
```

Answer (score 0):

[yata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9698684/yatu) answer is ok, but if you want to sort arraydata list by highest number, try this:

```
from operator import itemgetter
a.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
print(a[0])
#['bob', 56]
```

Always the highest number is on zero index if you use reverse True.